# Send and receive audio between PC and iPhone

Tags: windows, ios, audio

I would like to be able to use my headset for both my iPhone and PC at once. eg. Audio would play from both my phone (e.g. music, calls), and any applications on my PC, and both my phone and PC will be able to pick up audio from my microphone. My current solution is placing my earbuds underneath my headphones, but this is very impractical. Is this possible?

Comment: I doubt that this is possible. Unless you use one earpiece each from two sets, and have 2 mono channels :-)

Comment: You need a compact audio mixer, which can take multiple sources of audio.